# To extract Grabpass image as texture2d via script

Tags: unity, shaders

1. We applied it to the plane object using Grabpass.
2. I want to import the image shown in plane through script.
3. I want to make the imported image in texture2d format.
4. Is there a way?
5. Below is the relevant code.[image: rab]

Comment: The effort of copy pasting text is less than doing a screenshot and uploading the image. Why did you update a screnshot of code instead of copy pasting the text?

Comment: Please copy and paste the text opposed to using an image.